How to extract multiple elements using EXTRACT?
In Teradata SQL, is it possible to get multiple elements like the minute and second or year and date from a date/timestamp using extract? Like the line below but actually works?
select extract(minute, second from timestamp '2024-06-05 00:12:48');

I have tried a bunch of different operators like and, &, &&, _, etc and none of them work.
Otherwise, what would the difference be between using YEAR(TIMESTAMP '2024-06-05 00:12:48') and DAY(TIMESTAMP '2024-06-05 00:12:48') versus EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP'2024-06-05 00:12:48') and EXTRACT (DAY FROM TIMESTAMP'2024-06-05 00:12:48')?

The short answer is no, you cannot pull multiple parts from a date/timestamp like that.
You would have to pull them separately, cast them as strings, and concatenate them together.  But, what is your actual desired output?  There is probably a better way to do this, using to_char(<date column>, <format>)

@Andrew I was trying to figure out the difference between using YEAR() and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ) and saw that mysql seems to be able to get multiple parts of a date using extract which was the main difference between the two. Since Teradata SQL can only do one part at a time, is there any difference in using YEAR() vs EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ) in Teradata?

As far as I know, there is no difference.  Just as an FYI, it's DAYOFMONTH, no DAY.
